# tensorflow/keras utils module confusion between _api/v1/keras/ and python/keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I just try to import [vis_utils](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/vis_utils.py) from `tensorflow.keras` but it gives me

```
>>> import tensorflow.keras.utils.vis_utils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.utils.vis_utils'
```

Checking the location of utils tells me that it points to the wrong (?) directory:

```
>>> print(tensorflow.keras.utils.__file__)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/_api/v1/keras/utils/__init__.py
```

But it should actually point to `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/__init__.py`
I've installed everything via pip and tf version is 1.12 on my vanilla Ubuntu 16.04. Is the installation tainted or how do tell python to load the correct module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import tensorflow.python.keras.utils.vis_utils` should work.

Comment: I think it is, the github repo you link to is also under the python path.

Comment: but if I use native keras, like `import keras.utils.vis_utils`, everything works fine. This would mean that the APIs are actually different. And I think this is not intended.